# Adding local thumbnail to Discord embed and send it to a specific channel with Pycord

Tags: python, discord, attachment, pycord

Im trying to send an embed with a thumbnail attachment to a different specific channel.

Sending on the local channel with interactions or DMs works but not to a specific channel

```
import discord
from interactions import Attachment, User
from discord.ui import Select, View, Button
from discord.utils import get

thumbnailFile = "attachment://thumbnail-placeholder.png"
localThumbnail = discord.File("./Source/Images/thumbnail-placeholder.png")
embedConfirm.set_thumbnail(url=thumbnailFile)

await bot.get_channel(int(ADMINREPORTCHANNEL)).send(embed=embedConfirm, view=view, file=localThumbnail)
```

Any idea if i am doing something wrong?

I get this output when its trying to send the embed.

```
Ignoring exception in view <View timeout=None children=3> for item <Button style=<ButtonStyle.success: 3> url=None disabled=False label='Create report' emoji=None row=None>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ogunt\anaconda3\envs\discord\lib\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 371, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "C:\Users\ogunt\Desktop\Discord Bot\BusBot\main.py", line 342, in button_create
    await bot.get_channel(int(ADMINREPORTCHANNEL)).send(embed=embedConfirm, view=view, file=localThumbnail)
  File "C:\Users\ogunt\anaconda3\envs\discord\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1481, in send
    data = await state.http.send_files(
  File "C:\Users\ogunt\anaconda3\envs\discord\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 284, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as response:
  File "C:\Users\ogunt\anaconda3\envs\discord\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1138, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\ogunt\anaconda3\envs\discord\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 507, in _request
    req = self._request_class(
  File "C:\Users\ogunt\anaconda3\envs\discord\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 313, in __init__
    self.update_body_from_data(data)
  File "C:\Users\ogunt\anaconda3\envs\discord\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 507, in update_body_from_data
    body = body()
  File "C:\Users\ogunt\anaconda3\envs\discord\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\formdata.py", line 170, in __call__
    return self._gen_form_data()
  File "C:\Users\ogunt\anaconda3\envs\discord\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\formdata.py", line 163, in _gen_form_data
    self._writer.append_payload(part)
  File "C:\Users\ogunt\anaconda3\envs\discord\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\multipart.py", line 831, in append_payload
    size = payload.size
  File "C:\Users\ogunt\anaconda3\envs\discord\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\payload.py", line 379, in size
    return os.fstat(self._value.fileno()).st_size - self._value.tell()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can only send a thumbnail once then the file closes. So I created second variable to send to a different channel.

like this:

```
localThumbnail = discord.File("./Source/Images/thumbnail-placeholder.png")
localThumbnail2 = discord.File("./Source/Images/thumbnail-placeholder.png")
```

My thumbnail works now.